# How to use libvlc for low-frame-rate rtsp stream decoding

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, rtsp, latency, libvlc

I am using libvlc for RTSP h.264 bitstream decoding and display in PC. For the best experience (i.e. low latency), I uses the following options

```
:file-caching=0
:tcp-caching=0
:rtsp-caching=0
:network-caching=0
:clock-jitter=0
:avcodec-fast
```

With these parameters, the latency is acceptable in comparison to the open-source project "ONVIF device manager"(ODM) where FFMPEG is used for decoding.

When RTSP server deliver low frame-rate RTSP stream, (1 frame/second). These configuration will freeze after displaying a few frames (3-5 frames).

I have tried 2 different approaches

1. Disable synchronization by

   :clock-synchro=0

This will enable the decoding process to go on, however, an accumulated period of time lagging could be observed.

2. Use network-cache

My experiments shows that

```
:network-caching=1200
```

Will make decoding go smoothly, however, the latency is over 1-2 second in comparison to ODM.

Is there a way to handle the low frame rate issue in libvlc without providing such big latency?